# Building libloc_api on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I would like to build `libloc_api.so` from the Android source so that I can use of the native gps functions.

The source is in the `hardware/qcom/gps/loc_api/libloc_api` folder, but I'm not familiar with how to build one of these modules without building the whole source tree.

Does anyone know how I would just build the `libloc_api` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to build the **.so** file so that you can link against it. It is fine to get the library from a device, e.g.

```
adb pull /system/lib/libloc_api.so devicelib/libloc_api.so
```

Now your **Android.mk** should add **-Ldevicelib -lloc-api** to LOCAL_LDLIBS.

Note that this library is device-specific, and your app will fail if you try to load it on devices not based on Quallcom Snapdragon SoC.

But more importantly, this library is useless unless you work on a rooted device, because production phones only permit access to GPS hardware to a system service. All apps use the GPS (and other hardware, like Camera,  video codecs) through this service, and *going native* with NDK does not avoid the restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was able to create create a gps_device_t and get a GpsInterface instance, but now I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use the methods available to the interface to print NMEA messages.  Any idea how I would go about doing that?

Comment: I am afraid you need a rooted device and some tweaking of permissions to get a functioning instance. I'd love to be mistaken.

Comment: I am working with a rooted device, I can change permissions if I want.  I'm just not familiar with how to use the hardware abstraction layer and the callback functions associated with the gps interface.  Any clue?

Comment: OKey. Thanks for this clarification. Now your task becomes possible. Not easy, but possible.

Comment: ... but my answer resolves the original question, doesn't it? I believe it may improve your reputation if you accept the answer and ask a new question about "using libloc_api on a rooted Android device to get the raw NMEA messages"

Comment: Yea so how do I "accept the answer"? The only thing I can do is say the post was useful to me, but I can't upvote until I get a higher reputation.  Thanks for the help, I'm new to SO.

Comment: or did you just literally mean accept it and make a new post?

Comment: **absolutely!** The new question has to be worded and tagged differently, IMHO. And the question of _how to build_ (or avoid building from Google sources) is completely legitimate IMHO, so it won't be fair to overhaul it into another one. And try to give the new question a title that will prompt the relevant people to get involved!